# Adding Multiple Objects to a VB.net ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, object, arraylist

I'm creating a simple program in VB.net for saving and reading customer details; I would like to save the details as an object in an ArrayList and then retrieve the details when desired. I understand that my program is unfinished but I have pasted the code in question below. I am rather new to VB.net so I apologise in advance. Thank you.

The following is the code for my Customer object class,

```
Public Class Customer

Private CusID As Integer
Private CName As String
Private PostC As String
Private Phone As String

Public Sub New()

    CusID = 1
    CName = "Anom"
    PostC = "Anom"
    Phone = "Anom"

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal cid As Integer, ByVal aCName As String)

    CusID = cid
    CName = aCName

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property GetCName() As String

    Get
        Return CName
    End Get

End Property

Public WriteOnly Property SCName As String

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        CName = value
    End Set

End Property

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return "Customer id: " & CusID.ToString() & " Customer name: " & CName
End Function
```

End Class

This is my code to save a Customer object to the array, the array is defined earlier on in the module. Unfortunately for each new customer that I add to the array it overwrites the previous.

```
    Sub NewCustomer(ByRef CustL As ArrayList)

    Dim CustomerID As Integer
    Dim CustomerName As String

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the customer name: ")
    CustomerName = (Console.ReadLine())
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the customer ID: ")
    CustomerID = CInt(Console.ReadLine())

    CustL.Add(New Customer(CustomerID, CustomerName))

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to return to the main menu")
    Console.ReadKey()
    Console.Clear()
    Main()

End Sub
```

This is the code for retrieving a customers details from the array.

```
Sub ViewCustomer(ByRef CustL As ArrayList)

    Dim CustomerID As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the customer ID: ")
    CustomerID = CInt(Console.ReadLine())

    'Lookup customer from array here.

    Console.ReadKey("Press any key to return to the main menu")
    Console.Clear()
    Main()

End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend using a List(Of T) over an ArrayList.

Comment: how do you know new ones are replacing old ones?  Add should add.  I too would use List(T) or Collection(T), but you will need to change those PRIVATE Fields to Public Proprieties if you want to be able to identify your objects or use the data in them.

Comment: I too would use a `List(Of Customer)` and you shouldn't be passing any parameters `ByRef` either. You also shouldn't have separate `ReadOnly` and `WriteOnly` properties for the same value. None of those relate to your issue. What you think is happening is not happening. The code you've shown is adding distinct `Customer` objects to your `ArrayList`. Something else is happening that you haven't shown us. Why are those two methods calling `Main` for instance? `Main` should be the entry point for the app and not something you should be calling explicitly. You may be creating new `ArrayList`'s.

Answer (score 0):

'You are better of switch To an Object To hold your Customer information, And drop ArrayList For a strongly typed collection.' Once you turn each customer  to an object you will have a lot more control and what you want to do with them. 
like below

```
 Private CustList As New List(Of CustFiles)

 Public Class CustFiles
 Public Property custID As Integer
 Public Property custName As String
 End Class

Public Sub CustQueue(ByVal custName As String, ByVal custID  As Integer)
Dim CustObj As New CustFiles
CustObj .custName = custName 
CustObj.custID  = custID  
CustList.Add(CustObj)
End Sub

    For Each eachCust In CustList 
        MessageBox.Show(eachCust.custID  & " " & eachCust.custName )
    Next
```